# Array concatenation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, concatenation

I have a table view with 3 rows, if I select the first row , the item on the first row get saved in a array variable say `arrdata` , similarly when I select 2nd and 3rd row , I want it to get saved in the same variable `arrData`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSMutableArray.

For Ex.

```
NSMutableArray *arrData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Now, select the first row from table view

Use `[arrData addObject:[first row data]];`

For 2nd from table view

Use `[arrData addObject:[2nd row data]];`

For 3rd from table view

Use `[arrData addObject:[3rd row data]];`

And you can also add some condition for add data in to **arrData**, like if 1st row data is added then do't re-add it.

For Ex. When you select 1st row you can add 1, 2nd selection add 2, 3rd selection add 3 like [arrData addObject:@"1"]; etc.

Now, If you want to get data from **arrData**,

```
If (arrData.count > 0)
{
    NSString *fData = [arrData objectAtIndex:0]; // Here you get stored data from 1st selected row of table.
}
```

Comment: how can we store the 3 variables for selecting 3 rows

Comment: Means? Which 3 variables you want to store?

Comment: according to your example first row data ,2nd row data and 3rd row data , how will io get these 3 variables

Answer (score 0):

Create an `nsmutable` array and add objects by using method `addobject`

```
NSMutableArray *arrData =[[NSMutableArray alloc]ini];
```

On `Tableselection` method , add the following line

```
[arrdata addObject:your object];
```